# HTTP headers (for cache-control)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cdn, cloudflare

Is this statement correct?

> css and js should use private for proxy caching
>   https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageProxyCaching

I'm intending to use this directly for my hosting and alt. through a CDN, and wish to have the best settings for speed optimization, *TTFB*.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
<filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|gif|swf|eot|woff|otf|ttf|svg)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1209600, public"
</filesmatch>
# css and js should use private for proxy caching https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageProxyCaching
<filesmatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, private"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1209600, private"
</filesmatch>
<filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
```

Comment: It seems correct have you got any issue or error while using this snippet?

Comment: Not at all. `private` indicates for the files not to be cache-able. My question was how would that improve the optimization if you don't allow a CDN to cache your `css` and `js`? Don't you want your CDN to cache these files?